# using other schema except dbo in ndbunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ndbunit

I have a project with Ndbunit test that works well for dbo's tables. when I am using tables in other schema(for example schema.tableName) I get an Error. the Error is :

```
> NDbUnitQuery.GlobalTesting (TestFixtureSetUp):
> NDbUnit.Core.NDbUnitException :
> DbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet, string) failed for
> tableName = 'Code'   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException :
> Invalid object name 'Code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that the underlying .NET dataset designer isn't properly schema-aware.  In the Visual Studio dataset designer, you must 'manually' enter the schema prefix into each datatable definition's properties.  After that, NDbUnit should properly work with tables in other schemas.

For more detail, see http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/issues/detail?id=23